# Prove that $f(\limsup A_n)\subset \limsup f(A_n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $f(\limsup A_n)\subset \limsup f(A_n)$. Give an example where $f(\limsup A_n)\neq \limsup f(A_n)$.

I guess where I'm having trouble with this is what exactly does it mean to $f(\limsup A_n)$. I know what the $\limsup A_n$ but when it turns into a function then I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: Do you know what $\limsup f(A_n)$ is?

Comment: For a set $S$ (that is a subset of the domain of $f$), $f(S)$ is typical notation for the image of $S$ under $f,$ i.e. $$f(S)=\{f(x)\mid x\in S\}.$$

Comment: For the counter example let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=0$ for all x. Let $A_n=(n,\infty)$. Then $f(\limsup A_n)$ is  the empty set because $\limsup A_n$ is empty. On the other hand $f(A_n)=\{0\}$ for each n so  $\limsup  f(A_n) =\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(\lim \sup A_n)=\{f(x): x\in \lim \sup A_n\}.$

We have $$y\in  f(\lim \sup A_n)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists x \in \lim \sup A_n \;(y=f(x))\implies$$ $$\implies \exists x (y=f(x)\land \{n:x\in A_n\} \text { is infinite })\implies$$ $$\implies \exists x \;(\{n:y=f(x)\in f(A_n)\} \text { is infinite }) \implies$$ $$\implies \{n: y\in f(A_n)\} \text { is infinite})\implies $$ $$\implies y\in \lim \sup f(A_n).$$